# Prove $\{a(c):a(x) \in F[x]\}$ is an integral domain isomorphic to $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise G1.

> Let $F$ be a field, and let $c$ be transcendental over $F$.
>   Prove {$a(c):a(x) \in F[x]$} is an integral domain isomorphic to $F[x]$.

[Edited]

In general, if $A$ is an integral domain, then $A[x]$ is an integral domain.

Let $S_c =$ {$a(c):a(x) \in F[x]$}.  $S_c$ is an integral domain iff $S_c$ is a commutative ring with unity
that has no divisor of zero.

1. $S_c$ is obviously commutative and closed under addition and multiplication by the properties inherited from $F[x]$, which is an integral domain.  Note $F[x]$ is an integral domain for $F$ is a field.
2. $a(x)=1\in F[x]\implies a(c)=1\in S_c$.
3. Suppose $a_1(c)a_2(c) = 0$ for nonzero polynomials $a_1(x), a_2(x)\in F[x]$. 
   Let $b(x)=a_1(x)a_2(x)$. Then $b(c) = 0$, contradicting that $c$ is transcendental. Hence $a_1(c)a_2(c) = 0$ implies either $a_1(x)$ or $a_2(x)$ is zero; that is, $S_c$ has no divisor of zero.

This completes the proof that $S_c$ is an integral domain.

Let $\sigma_c: F[x]\rightarrow S_c$ such that $\sigma_c(a(x)) = a(c)$.
Note $\sigma_c$ is a ring homomorphism from $F[x]$ onto $S_c$.
Furthermore, $a(c)= b(c)\implies a(x)= b(x)$, for otherwise suppose $a(x)\ne b(x)$, then $a(x)-b(x)\ne 0\implies a(c)-b(c) \ne 0$, as $c$ is transcendental, contradicting $a(c)=b(c)$.  Hence $\sigma_c$ is bijective and therefore an isomorphism; that is, $S_c\cong F[x]$.

Comment: $F$ might be a field, but $F[x]$ never is.

Comment: Shorter: The map $F[x]\to \{\,a(x):a(x)\in F[x]\,\}$ induced by $x\mapsto c$ is obviously an epimorphism of rings. As $c$ is transcendental, its kernel is trivial,hence it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim that that $\sigma_c$ is injective is rather unconvincing. Also, as suggested in the comments, you can skip the entire proof that $S_c$ is an integral domain; once you prove that $S_c\cong F[x]$ it follows that $S_c$ is an integral domain because $F[x]$ is. Overall your proof focuses on the wrong points; you gloss over key facts without any argument, and elaborate on completely irrelevant facts.

To prove that $S_c\cong F[x]$ indeed the most efficient approach is to note that the ring homomorphism
$$\sigma_c:\ F[x]\ \longrightarrow\ S_c:\ a\ \longmapsto\ a(c),$$
is surjective by definition of $S_c$, and injective because $a(c)=0$ implies $a=0$ because $c$ is transcendental. Then $S_c$ is an integral domain because $F[x]$ is.

Comment: Agree.  I've fixed the injectivity argument in the OP anyway.  Thank you for the answer.